# How to Activate Battery Module in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet, energy

I'm trying to use the InetSimpleBattery module to collect energy data of the simulation I'm running. Whenever I run a simulation, energy values are always constant (no energy drain).
So I tried to modify the following parameters in the ini file:

```
**.usage_radio_idle = 575mA #[mA]
**.usage_radio_recv = 4000mA #[mA]
**.usage_radio_sleep = 25mA #[mA]
**.usage_radio_send = 4000mA #[mA]
```

But I get "unused entry" warning and the energy values are still constant with no change over time. So, to make sure I'm using radio (since it's the only module that drains energy in inet 2.x) Itried this in my ini file:

```
**.wlan[*].typename = "Ieee80211Nic"
```

But then I got this When I started my simulation:

> "Could not find ChannelControl module with name 'channelControl' in
>   the top-level network"

Any thoughts about this?
I need to have valid values for the energy plots.